Clean the house
A friend of mine put a reminder to clean his house before going out, in the inner-facing side of the front door. As a humorous note, he wrote it in Latin, attached to a well-known quote:

Memento mori... et domum emundare.

Which lead me to wonder if emundo was the best choice of a verb for the act of making things clean (but also put in order) at home.
A few alternatives come to mind:

mundo
purgo (more dubious, I think)
ordino

But it wasn't easy to me to find attested examples (which would be ideal), and the definitions by L&S were a bit too concise for me. Moreover, I became insecure about how idiomatic the the English verb to clean is in itself in this meaning: in Spanish you don't clean the house, but more frequently one does the cleaning (hace el aseo, house implied, and aseo not being derived from a verb) or even tidies the house up (ordena).
So: what is a demonstrably suitable verb for cleaning the house, or is there other idiomatic way of conveying the whole action?

That you have bubilia emundare suggests the word is fine, if a bit particular. Did you have particular reservations about it?

Another options is everro (or verro). It works with domus but it seems to mean more literal sweeping. Not sure there is a nice fit that covers both "to clean" and "to put in order".

@cmw, nothing objective, to tell the truth. It just sounded uncommon to me, and maybe confirmation bias when I saw meanings in II in the L&S entry (purify and the like): they suggested to me it wasn't quite what I was looking form.

@d_e, nice finding! After your suggestion I found that Columella in De Re Rustica 7.4.5 uses Stabula vero frequenter everrenda et purganda. Which could be a nice way of describing cleaning the stables. It would be nice to see it applied to a house too.
